# Concatenate images from folders by their ORDER in python

Tags: python, opencv, concatenation, python-imaging-library

I know how to concatenate two exact images, but I need to combine two images each from their own folder. I cannot do it by name of the image or don´t know how to do it with a list of pairs. **Is it possible to concatenate all images (always two, one from each folder) by the order of images?** They are sorted by time of download so they match in order, not in exact time of download.
Thanks.

Comment: You can loop through image files from two folders simultaneously using `zip` and concatenate them

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work !

```
import cv2 as cv
import os

folder1 = r"folder1_path"
folder2= r"folder2_path"

for img1,img2 in zip(os.listdir(folder1), os.listdir(folder2)):
    img1=cv2.imread(img1)
    img2=cv2.imread(img2)
    concatenate_image= cv2.vconcat([img1, img2])

     cv.imshow('Final_image', comcatenate_image)
     cv.waitKey(0)
```

Make sure both folder images are in same dimensions.